# Replacing placeholders in prepared statement OleDbCommand.Parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, prepared-statement, oledb, sql-like

I'm trying to perform a simple query on my MS Access DB from a Console Application through prepared statements.

The query tries to look for the desired value either in the "targa" field or in the "auto" field, to simplify the user interface with only one research label.

```c#
//grab field from GUI
string ricerca = Ricerca.Text;
string queryTarga = "SELECT * FROM [Codici] WHERE targa = ? OR auto LIKE '%?%'";
command = new OleDbCommand(queryTarga, con);


command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar,ricerca.Length,"targa").Value = ricerca;
command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar, ricerca.Length,"auto").Value = ricerca;
```

If I insert a known value for the first field "targa", the lookup works out with no issues.
If I insert anything for "auto", the lookup never returns any value!

The problem is that '%?%' gets interpreted in a weird way due to the single quotes and it's not recognising and setting the parameter correctly. By hardcoding the "ricerca" variable in the query string (without using '?') it works just fine:

```c#
string queryTarga = "SELECT * FROM [Codici] WHERE targa = ? OR auto LIKE '%" + ricerca + "%'";
```

Does anyone have a clue of how to set the parameter?

Comment: `LIKE '%' + ? +'%'` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string queryTarga = "SELECT * FROM [Codici] WHERE targa = ? OR auto LIKE @p1";

command = new OleDbCommand(queryTarga, con);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "%" + Ricerca.Text + "%");
```